# How do we calculate the escape velocity of galaxies?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way, velocity

How do we calculate the escape velocity of galaxies?
Do we have to know the total mass?
What is the escape velocity for Milky Way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the escape velocity from the region we find ourselves in the milky way is **544 Km/s +- 10%**.

This number, and an extensive explanation of how it was calculated can be found on a paper called [The RAVE Survey: Constraining the Local Galactic Escape Speed](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0611671v2.pdf)

Also important to consider is the fact that we already are at aproximately **220 Km/s** because of the **sun's orbital velocity**, so the actual value needed to get there from earth is much lower.